# Error: A value of type 'Future<ListView>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I'm tryng to read data from Cloud Firestore (working) and put the data in a ListView containing a graphic widget (Order) that shows price, date and product, but when I'm trying to return the data from the method this error shows up.
The target is to return the data of the user passed to the db_utility constructor.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'order.dart';

class db_utility extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userID;
  const db_utility(this.userID, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: users.doc(userID).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text("error");
        } else if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return const Text("no data found");
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return getListOfOrders();
        }
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And this is the method that returns the ListView:

```
Future<ListView> getListOfOrders() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('completed_orders')
        .where('user', isEqualTo: userID)
        .orderBy('timestamp')
        .get();
    final data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    List<Order> orders = <Order>[];
    for (var o in data) {
      orders.add(Order((o as Map)['price'], 'date of today', o['product']));
    }
    return ListView(children: orders,);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the future builder getting `users.doc(userID).get(),`?

Comment: @h8moss to get the username's document from cloud firestore, in the code the username is `userID`: if it exists then shows the data connected to `userID` username

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @nvoigt nop but thanks anyway, Yeasin Sheikh's answer solved everything

Answer (score 1):

`getListOfOrders()` is another future method, you can use nested `FutureBuilder` .

In that case, instead of `return getListOfOrders();` use another `FutureBuilder` like previous one. But you can do the operation on single future method.

You can also check [multiple method on a future builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50626949/10157127)