# Flutter - Future Builder with two async functions

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to use FutureBuilder, but make it build after waiting for 2 async functions to end.

In the Flutter docs, it says `Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future.` So it builds after one function, not waiting for the other.

```dart
Future<int> futureInit() async {
  await functionA();
  await functionB();
  return 0;
}
```

My code is like this, so the future builder builds after just function A.

How can I make it wait for the both functions to end and then start building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to know how to handle future function.
there are 2 approach. with `await` and with `then`
here my article explain more about it : [await vs then in Flutter](https://pmatatias.medium.com/await-vs-then-in-flutter-28c2ce600cea)

if you want to handle 2 future function in 1 `FutureBuilder`,you can use `Future.wait`. here an old question related:https://stackoverflow.com/a/50627153/12838877

```
Future<A> functionA();
Future<B> functionB();
FutureBuilder(
  future: Future.wait([functionA, functionB]),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
    snapshot.data[0]; //functionA
    snapshot.data[1]; //functionB
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will work. you can use .then() function. It will execute one after another. please check this and revert

```
Future<int> futureInit() async {
    await functionA().then((func) async {
      await functionB();
    });
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. To add, it just starts building after function A starts and before it ends. So it's like [funcA start -> builder build start -> funcA end]

Answer (score 0):

You can delay your `FutureBuilder` by using:

```
     Future<int> futureInit() async {
      await functionA();
      await functionB();
    // Make your delay here.
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    // And trigger future builder.
      return 0;
    }
```